# How can I recompile js file in dist folder?

Tags: functions, wp-dependencies

I'm working on a project that loads a minified js file from my theme into a page `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme-2021/dist/app.js?ver=5.9' id='app-js'></script>`

I have a webpack.mix.js file in my theme root directory:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

const dist = `dist`

mix
  .options({ processCssUrls: false })
  .copyDirectory('resources/fonts', dist)
  .copyDirectory('resources/images', dist)
  .js('resources/js/app.js', dist)
  .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', dist);
```

and a package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.1",
    "reset-css": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-mq": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.37.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0"
  }
}
```

I've made changes to the `resources/js/app.js` file and I'm trying to understand how can I make the app rebuild the file? I've tried from command line `npx webpack` but without success. Maybe it's done via a plugin?

Can anyone explain how is this thing working? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your package.json should have more in it than just that. You should see a section for "scripts". If you do `npm install` and then check which scripts are registered, you may have one called "build". In which case, you can do `npm run build`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that calling the following from your theme folder should do the job:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

Source: "[How to Use Webpack in WordPress](https://wptips.dev/webpack-in-wordpress/)".